# How to convert lambda filters with dynamic values to method references

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream, method-reference

I have some Java code which filters a list based on some input. It currently uses a lambda, for example:

```
public List<ComplexObject> retrieveObjectsFilteredByTags(List<String> allowedTags) {
    List<ComplexObject> complexObjects = retrieveAllComplexObjects();
    return complexObjects
                .stream()
                .filter( compObject -> allowedTags.contains(compObject.getTag()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

What I want to do is to move the filter logic to another method to make it re-usable and easily unit testable. So I wanted to use a method reference in place of the lambda passed to the filter method. Easy to do if the filter logic is fairly static (i.e. list of allowed tags is known at compile time) but I can't figure out how to do this with dynamic data in the filter.

What I wanted was some way to use a method reference and then pass the second dynamic param i.e.

```
public List<ComplexObject> retrieveObjectsFilteredByTags(List<String> allowedTags) {
    List<ComplexObject> complexObjects = retrieveAllComplexObjects();
    return complexObjects
                .stream()
                .filter(this::filterByAllowedTags, allowedTags)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

So is it possible to do what I want or am I possibly approaching this situation incorrectly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest passing in a `Predicate` as a parameter. That way the caller can filter based on any criteria it wants, including `allowedTags` or whatever:

```
public List<ComplexObject> retrieveObjectsFilteredBy(Predicate<ComplexObject> pred) {
    List<ComplexObject> complexObjects = retrieveAllComplexObjects();
    return complexObjects.stream()
        .filter(pred)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

This would be called like so:

```
    List<String> allowedTags = ... ;
    List<ComplexObject> result =
        retrieveObjectsFilteredBy(cobj -> allowedTags.contains(cobj.getTag()));
```

But you could go even further, depending on how much refactoring you're willing to do. Instead of "retrieve" returning a `List`, how about having it return a `Stream`? And instead of the retrieve-filter method returning a `List`, how about having it return a `Stream` too?

```
public Stream<ComplexObject> retrieveObjectsFilteredBy2(Predicate<ComplexObject> pred) {
    Stream<ComplexObject> complexObjects = retrieveAllComplexObjects2();
    return complexObjects.filter(pred);
}
```

And the calling side would look like this:

```
    List<String> allowedTags = ... ;
    List<ComplexObject> result =
        retrieveObjectsFilteredBy2(cobj -> allowedTags.contains(cobj.getTag()))
            .collect(toList());
```

Now if you look at it carefully, you can see that the retrieve-filter method isn't adding any value at all, so you might just as well inline it into the caller:

```
    List<String> allowedTags = ... ;
    List<ComplexObject> result =
        retrieveAllComplexObjects2()
            .filter(cobj -> allowedTags.contains(cobj.getTag()))
            .collect(toList());
```

Of course, depending upon what the caller wants to do, it might not want to collect the results into a list; it might want to process the results with `forEach()`, or something else.

Now you can still factor out the filter into its own method, for testing/debugging, and you can use a method reference:

```
boolean cobjFilter(ComplexObject cobj) {
    List<String> allowedTags = ... ;
    return allowedTags.contains(cobj.getTag());
}

    List<ComplexObject> result =
        retrieveAllComplexObjects2()
            .filter(this::cobjFilter)
            .collect(toList());
```

If you don't want the filter to have the allowed tags built into it, you can change it from being a predicate into a higher-order function that returns a predicate instead:

```
Predicate<ComplexObject> cobjFilter(List<String> allowedTags) {
    return cobj -> allowedTags.contains(cobj.getTag());
}

    List<String> allowedTags = ... ;
    List<ComplexObject> result =
        retrieveAllComplexObjects2()
            .filter(cobjFilter(allowedTags))
            .collect(toList());
```

Which of these variations makes the most sense depends on what your application looks like and what kind of dynamicism you require in filtering.

Answer (score 2):

How about the following? It extracts the predicate in a separate method to make it easily testable, and can be reused easily.

```
public Predicate<ComplexObject> tagAllowed(List<String> allowedTags) {
    return (ComplexObject co) -> allowedTags.contains(co.getTag());
}

public List<ComplexObject> retrieveObjectsFilteredByTags(List<String> allowedTags) {
    List<ComplexObject> complexObjects = retrieveAllComplexObjects();
    return complexObjects
                .stream()
                .filter(tagAllowed(allowedTags))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem with the method reference `this::filterByAllowedTags` is that it has the shape:

```
(ComplexObject, List<String>) -> boolean
```

But it's being passed into `filter()` which expects a lambda of the shape:

```
(ComplexObject) -> boolean
```

In other words, `this::filterByAllowedTags` can never be a `Predicate`, but it could be some alternate interface `Predicate2`. Then you'd also need an overload of filter which takes a `Predicate2`.

[Eclipse Collections](http://www.eclipse.org/collections/) (formerly GS Collections) has the method `select()` which behaves just like `filter()`, and `selectWith()` which behaves like the overload I just described.

Using `select()`:

```
public List<ComplexObject> retrieveObjectsFilteredByTags(List<String> allowedTags)
{
    // retrieveAllComplexObjects returns a MutableList, possibly FastList
    MutableList<ComplexObject> complexObjects = retrieveAllComplexObjects();
    // select() returns MutableList here which extends List
    return complexObjects.select(compObject -> allowedTags.contains(compObject.getTag()));
}
```

Using `selectWith()`:

```
public List<ComplexObject> retrieveObjectsFilteredByTags(List<String> allowedTags)
{
    // retrieveAllComplexObjects returns a MutableList, possibly FastList
    MutableList<ComplexObject> complexObjects = retrieveAllComplexObjects();
    // select() returns MutableList here which extends List
    return complexObjects.selectWith(this::filterByAllowedTags, allowedTags);
}

private boolean filterByAllowedTags(ComplexObject complexObject, List<String> allowedTags)
{
    return allowedTags.contains(complexObject.getTag());
}
```

**Note:** I am a committer for Eclipse Collections.